# Make image's opacity using alpha in RGBA

Tags: java, image, opacity, rgb, rgba

I tried to make a simple program which load an image, make it blue effect, and also make it half transperant. I'm doing it by running on the image pixels and change the RGB's blue value and alpha value. I successed to make a nice blue effect to the image. But I couldn't manage to change the image opacity. It seems that no matter how I change the alpha value of the pixels, it doesn't effect the image.

Here is my code:

```
try {
    image1 = ImageIO.read(new File("image1.png"));
} catch(IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}


for(int x=0;x<image1.getWidth();x++) {
    for(int y=0;y<image1.getHeight();y++) {
        int rgb = image1.getRGB(x, y);
        Color color = new Color(rgb);
        int r = color.getRed();
        int g = color.getGreen();
        int b = color.getBlue();
        int a = color.getAlpha();

        System.out.println(a);
        a= 100;
        if(b<155)
            b+=100;
        else
            b=255;

        color = new Color(r,g,b,a);

        image1.setRGB(x, y, color.getRGB());
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
I also tried this. still doesn't work:

```
for(int x=0;x<image1.getWidth();x++) {
    for(int y=0;y<image1.getHeight();y++) {
        int rgb = image1.getRGB(x, y);
        Color color = new Color(rgb,true);
        int r = color.getRed();
        int g = color.getGreen();
        int b = color.getBlue();
        int a = color.getAlpha();

        a= 100;
        if(b<155)
            b+=100;
        else
            b=255;


        rgb = rgb | b;
        rgb = rgb & 0x33ffffff;


        image1.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code which you use to define image1?

Answer (score 1):

Use an [AlphaComposite](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html):

```
BufferedImage img = //some code here
BufferedImage imgClone = //some clone of img, but let its type be BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
Graphics2D imgCloneG = imgClone.createGraphics();
imgCloneG.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.DST_IN, 0.5f));
imgCloneG.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
//imgClone is now img at half alpha
```

`imgClone` can be made like this:

```
...
imgClone = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), 
                             BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D imgCloneG = imgClone.createGraphics();
imgCloneG.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
imgCloneG.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.DST_IN, 0.5f));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Color` constructor that takes only an `int` creates an opaque color (with alpha 255).  When you take out the alpha again with `getAlpha()`, it's always 255 here.

Relevant Java `Color` code, from line 413 (at least in Java 1.7):

```
public Color(int rgb) {
    value = 0xff000000 | rgb;
}
```

The most significant 8 bytes are set, overwriting whatever alpha component was there.

To preserve the alpha component, you need to use the [`Color` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int,%20boolean%29) that takes an `int` for the values *and* a `boolean` for whether it has an alpha component.

```
Color color = new Color(rgb, true);
```

Comment: so what the meaning of this Constructor: Color(r,g,b,a); When do i need to use it?

Comment: The Color constructor that takes 4 ints -- the individual components red, green, blue, and alpha, from 0-255.  This is not to be confused with the constructor that takes 4 floats -- the individual components red, green, blue, and alpha, as decimals from 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: is the setRGB use Color behind the scenes? I updated the code and it still doesn't work. I couldn't understand how to use your code. because Im only use Color to disassamble rbg int to it's parts and couldn't figured out how the Color object affect my image directly